# Getting A Route Parameter for Resolve

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm getting killed by my inability to grok Angular-UI UI-Router.  I have a state defined as follows:

```
$stateProvider
    .state('member', {
        url: '/member/:membersId',
        templateUrl: 'templates/member.html',
        resolve : {
            // From examples for testing
            simpleObj:  function(){
                return {value: 'simple!'};
            },

            memberDetails : function(FamilyService,$state) {

                return FamilyService.getMember($state.current.params.membersId);

            }
        },
        controller: 'MemberController'
    });
```

Since the docs say $stateParams aren't available, I'm using $state.current.params.  Should be fine.  Instead, I get dead air.  I can't access the `membersId` to save my life.

To test my service and make sure it's not the problem, I hard coded in a membersId and the controller gets the `memberDetails` result as well as the `simpleObj` result.  So, Service and Controller and working great.

Example of that hardcoded:

```
$stateProvider
    .state('member', {
        url: '/member/:membersId',
        templateUrl: 'templates/member.html',
        resolve : {
            // From examples for testing
            simpleObj:  function(){
                return {value: 'simple!'};
            },

            memberDetails : function(FamilyService,$state) {

                return FamilyService.getMember('52d1ebb1de46c3f103000002');

            }
        },
        controller: 'MemberController'
    });
```

Even though the docs say you can't use $stateParams in a resolve, I've tried it anyway.  It doesn't work either.

`return FamilyService.getMember($stateParams.membersId);`

How in the world do I get the `membersId` param to get passed into the FamilyService for the resolve?

I don't have much hair left to pull out; so, someone save me please.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I finally figured this out.  It was quite simple and in the docs.  Despite reading several times, I overlooked it each time.  I needed to inject $stateParams into the resolve:

```
$stateProvider
    .state('member', {
        url: '/member/:membersId',
        templateUrl: 'templates/member.html',
        resolve : {
            simpleObj:  function(){
                return {value: 'simple!'};
            },

            memberDetails : function(FamilyService,$stateParams) {
                return FamilyService.getMember($stateParams.membersId);
            }
        },
        controller: 'MemberController'
    });
```

I still don't understand why the documentation says this is not possible.

> Two Important $stateParams Gotchas
>
> The $stateParams object is only populated after the state is activated
>   and all dependencies are resolved. This means you won't have access to
>   it in state resolve functions. Use $state.current.params instead.
>   $stateProvider.state('contacts.detail', {      resolve: { 
>         someResolve: function($state){ 
>            //*** We cannot use $stateParams here, the service is not ready** //
>            // **Use $state.current.params instead ***//
>            return $state.current.params.contactId + "!" 
>         };     },    // ... })

Comment: Sorry for the incorrect docs. I removed that 'gotcha' so this will not mislead anyone moving forward.

Comment: Docs seem to be saying `$route.current.params` now, which seem to be working in my case. `Be aware that ngRoute.$routeParams will still refer to the previous route within these resolve functions. Use $route.current.params to access the new route parameters, instead.`  https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/provider/$routeProvider?p0=dataCollectionProvider%20%3C-%20dataCollection%20%3C-%20PageController

Comment: @seb You are looking at the wrong documentation: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki